# How to use module path in react js

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am to use path like

```
import Router from 'routes'
```

instead of

```
import Router from './routes'
```

i already add .env file with below code

```
NODE_PATH=./src
NODE_ENV=production
```

Comment: If you are using babel.js look up [.babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babelrc.html)

Comment: no. i did not add any babelrc file

Comment: How are you building/bundling your aplication?

Comment: not i added .babelrc file
`
{  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "test": "./test",
        "underscore": "lodash"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
`

is it fine ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a `.env` file at the root level (same level as package.json)

2) Set an environment variable, `NODE_PATH to src/`

```
import { Auth } from 'containers/Auth/Auth';
```

This works with create-react-app

if you are not using create-react-app you could try babel-plugin-module-resolver

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver
```

Specify the plugin in your .babelrc with the custom root or alias

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "test": "./test",
        "underscore": "lodash"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: do i need .babelrc file?

Comment: are you using create-react-app CLI? if so then no. if you are not using the CLI you can use babel-plugin-module-resolver

Comment: i am using CLI but its still not working. here is my .babelrc file
{
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./src"],
      "alias": {
        "test": "./test",
        "underscore": "lodash"
      }
    }]
  ]
}

Comment: I understand that if you are using CLI you don't need to add the babel file, unless you are using it for another purpose. Please take a look at this plugin babel-plugin-module-resolver. do a npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-module-resolver and see if you still have the same problem.

Comment: is your environment variable set to NODE_PATH to src/ ?

Comment: i make a file .env with this code

 NODE_PATH=./src